# match the same objects in two lists and see the value

Tags: python, oop

I have two classes in here that generate two lists.

```
class one: 
    def __init__(self, name, age): 
        self.name = name 
        self.age = age
   
# creating list       
list1 = [] 
 
# appending instances to list 
list1.append( one('A', 2) )
list1.append( one('B', 40) )
list1.append( one('C', 44) )

class two(object):
    def __init__(self, name, gender):
        self.name = name 
        self.gender = gender

# creating list       
list2 = []

# appending instances to list 
list2.append( two('A', 'F') )
list2.append( two('E', 'F') )
list2.append( two('F', 'M') )
```

What I am trying to do is to find the matched names within these two lists of objects. For this, I am using filter as follows:

```
matched = list(filter(lambda x: x.name in [obj.name for obj in list2], list1))
print(matched[0].name)
A
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to find a matched object? The above way to find the matched works, but doesn't seem to be the best way to do so for large lists. Also, I am wondering how else I can extract the attributes of the object?

Comment: typo(?), your `list2` should presumably be adding instances of class `two`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching `list2` every time, create a set of its names and check that.

```
list2_names = {obj.name for obj in list2}
matches = list(filter(lambda x: x.name in list2_names, list1))
```

If you need to search for names in these lists frequently, it might be better to make them dictionaries instead of lists.

Comment: Thanks. What would be also the best way to access the matches attributes?

Comment: Loop through matches an access the attributes normally with `element.name` and `element.age`.